# RSyslog Unknown Priority Name

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

Im trying to configure rsyslog to forward syslog messages to a remote host. But when i updated the config to forward to a specific ip and host, im getting this error:

> rsyslogd-3000: unknown priority name ""

Can someone help me please?

Rsyslog 8.4 running on SuSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP 2

```
#
# enable this, if you want to keep all messages
# in one file
#*.*                    -/var/log/allmessages
# Some foreign boot scripts require local7
#
local0.*;local1.*           -/var/log/localmessages
local2.*;local3.*           -/var/log/localmessages
local4.*;local5.*           -/var/log/localmessages
local6.*;local7.*           -/var/log/localmessages

*.* @@172.25.115.237:514
###
```

Comment: Are you getting another errors in log ? Maybe reference to incorrect string of config?

Comment: Also try to use syntaxis like: `local0,local1.*           -/var/log/localmessages` for all local-events.

Comment: Check for non-printing characters in the file with `cat -vet`.

Comment: @Alexey No, as per double checking that's the only error that come up everytime i restarted the service. 

I believe i did that, but instead i targeted all.

My understanding of this line:
*.* @@172.25.115.237:514

Means that all logs to be forwarded to the IP:PORT.

Comment: @meuh I got something like this: https://imgur.com/qSVSqgB

Comment: Did you load the correct module at the start: `$ModLoad imtcp`

Comment: Actually, i dont see any $ModLoad codes on the /etc/rsyslog.conf

Comment: `$ModLoad imtcp` provides TCP syslog reception, usually it's not required for client config `/etc/rsyslog.conf`, only for server config. @Kenneh  
Have you get this error immediately after adding string `*.* @@172.25.115.237:514`? Or it still was before? Did you try to set some particular prioritet, for example: `*.warn @@172.25.115.237:514` ? 
Also it would be useful to look all configuration of `/etc/rsyslog.conf `.